# SimpleITK copy headers/metadata to align segmentation with image

Tags: python, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, medical, simpleitk

I am trying to copy all the metadata/header information from one image to another.

I have a segmentation (original_image) that when I overlap it with the MRI image it comes from it overlaps as expected (comparing it in 3D Slicer, for instance). I perform some operations on Seg3D and when I save the image (new_image) the overlap doesn't occur anymore, it's moved and rotated. I have the function below using SimpleITK (sitk) to try to copy all the possible metadata/header/information from the original_image but it still doesn't align. The center seems to be fine, but that's it. I understand that there are probably redundancies in the script, I was trying all possible options.

```
def save_itk_keeping_header(new_image, original_image, filename):

  image_bad_header_itk=sitk.ReadImage(new_image)
  image_good_header=sitk.ReadImage(original_image)

  image_bad_header_itk.CopyInformation(image_good_header)

  image_bad_header_itk.SetDirection(image_good_header.GetDirection())
  image_bad_header_itk.SetOrigin(image_good_header.GetOrigin())
  [image_bad_header_itk.SetMetaData(key,image_good_header.GetMetaData(key)) for key in image_good_header.GetMetaDataKeys()]

  sitk.WriteImage(image_bad_header_itk, filename, True)
```

The output I get is below - it seems that it should be rotated 90 degrees. Any idea what am I missing? In case it helps, the grey image is an MRI, so they are usually rotated in contrast with CT images that are align with the XYZ coordinate system.

[image]

Comment: The main geometric data for an image would be Origin, Direction and Spacing.  You're missing Spacing, but that doesn't look like the cause of your problem.

Comment: I'd guess is a coordinate system problem.  Take a look at Slicer's Wiki about it:  https://www.slicer.org/wiki/Coordinate_systems and maybe ask the folks on Slicer's Discourse (discourse.slicer.org)

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a coordinate system issue, my guess is that Seg3D moves the image to align it with whichever XYZ system it has. But I would have thought that by copying the info from the header that should be solved, but apparently not... About Slicer's forum it seems that is more about Slicer-related questions, but this is a nrrd/simpleITK issue, not Slicer

Comment: For anyone using Nifti format, I simply could not get sitk coordinates to work. For a dataset that had a non-zero origin, sitk.ReadImage() or GetOrigin() would not pick it up. I ended up using nibabel.